# Counting repeated strings in a list and printing

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list containing a number of strings. Some of the strings are repeated so I want to count how many times they are repeated. For the singular strings I will only print it, for the repeating strings I want to print the number of duplications it has. the code is as follows:

```
for string in list:
    if list.count(string) > 1:
    print(string+" appeared: ")
    print(list.count(string))
elif list.count(string) == 1:
    print(string)
```

However it has some problems as it is printing all the instances of the repeated strings. For example, if there are two "hello" strings in the list, it will print `hello appeared 2` for twice. So is there a way to skip to check all the instances of the repeated strings? Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` for this.

Comment: Side note: never name a variable after a built-in. Use `lst` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list.count` in a loop is expensive. It will parse the entire list for each word. That's O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. You *can* loop over a set of words, but that's O(m*n) complexity, still not great.

Instead, you can use `collections.Counter` to parse your list once. Then iterate your dictionary key-value pairs. This will have O(m+n) complexity.

```
lst = ['hello', 'test', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'hope', 'this', 'works']

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lst)

for word, count in c.items():
    if count == 1:
        print(word)
    else:
        print(f'{word} appeared: {count}')

hello
test appeared: 2
this appeared: 2
is
a
hope
works
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `set`

**Ex:**

```
for string in set(list):
    if list.count(string) > 1:
        print(string+" appeared: ")
        print(list.count(string))
    elif list.count(string) == 1:
        print(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

To create:

```
In [166]: import collections

In [169]: d = collections.Counter(['hello', 'world', 'hello'])
```

To display:

```
In [170]: for word, freq in d.items():
     ...:     if freq > 1:
     ...:         print('{0} appeared {1} times'.format(word, freq))
     ...:     else:
     ...:         print(word)
     ...:
hello appeared 2 times
world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `collections.counter` like so -

```
import collections
result = dict(collections.Counter(list))
```

Another way to do this manually is:

```
result = {k, 0 for k in set(list)}
for item in list:
    result[item] += 1
```

Also, you should not name your list as list as its python's inbuilt type. Now both the methods will give you dicts like -

```
{"a": 3, "b": 1, "c": 4, "d": 1}
```

Where `keys` are the unique values from your list and values are how many time a key has appeared in your list